# What is the difference between the find_all() function and the SoupStrainer of the BeautifulSoup package?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The following code is used to print on screen the  tags of the html_doc, which is a variable that contains html code:

```
from bs4 import SoupStrainer

only_a_tags = SoupStrainer("a")

print(BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser", parse_only=only_a_tags).prettify())
```

The following code returns the same result:

```
print(BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser").find_all("a").prettify())
```

What is the difference between using the SoupStrainer and the find_all() function?

Could we use both SoupStrainer and Find_all()?

I found the following but can not understand what it does:

```
BeautifulSoup(response,parse_only=SoupStrainer("a",href=True)).find_all("a")
```

Answer (score 0):

find_all returns an iterable of navigable strings, SoupStrainer parses the page to limit your soup with certain parameters.

To iterate over each of the anchors in the page to perform some action on each one you'd use find_all.  If you just want to parse out everything from the page except the anchors you'd use SoupStrainer.  Using them together just makes it a little bit more efficient.